# Error in skinning the application while Opening the MongoVUE

Tags: mongodb

I download trial version of MongoVUE. After 15 days when i open it,gives error as
"Error in skinning the application"
How extend trail version period to work with MongoVUE
can any one help on this?

Answer (score 6):

Locate and delete "`user.config`" file in your user settings folder.

An example location might be:

```
C:\Users\yourcomputername\AppData\Local\MangoUI\MongoVUE.exe_Url_bxdk3k1matlnau5pbxnyltimzt4sf2jl\1.5.3.0
```

Once deleted, the program will run normally.

Comment: Be careful not to delete MongoVUE folder from the same location. I did that by mistake and lost all my saved connections.